# How to build our own workflow system using the Grails Activiti plugin

Tags: grails, workflow, grails-plugin, activiti

I want to build my own workflow system using the Grails Activiti plugin. What are the procedures to do this? Can anyone help me out?

I have referred to this [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/grails-activiti-plugin/) and an [example](https://code.google.com/p/grails-activiti-plugin/wiki/VacationRequestSampleApplication) given.

I have installed the Grails Activiti plugin in my project. I also downloaded and installed the vacation request sample application in my project and saw how it is working.

Answer (score 3):

Right now, I don't think there's step-by-step instructions to take you through implementing the Grails Activiti plugin. I'm in a similar boat (a development shop using Grails that would like to implement a workflow engine), and so far the Activiti plugin hasn't been really helpful. Those who are using it [don't actually seem to be leveraging the integration it provides between GORM and Activiti](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/grails-activiti-plugin/aXJRxaom9ac/wmc57WjKqWcJ).

Broadly, here are the steps that I would recommend for using Activiti in Grails; you could probably take or leave the Activiti Plugin.

1. [Create the Activiti engine in your database](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#creatingDatabaseTable). If you're using an in-memory H2 database and letting Grails do the create/drop statements, you may need to add the h2 scripts to your application's startup process.
2. Map a process that you want in your Grails app in the BPMN 2.0 XML format. You can use the [Activiti Eclipse Designer](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#activitiDesigner), which will plug into GGTS just fine, fire up Activiti Explorer somewhere and use the web-based designer, or code the raw XML your own bad self.
3. Include Activiti as a dependency in your Grails application. You can do that by including the Activiti Grails plugin in BuildConfig.groovy, or by just including the Activiti engine jar as a dependency by itself (see below).
4. Use calls to the [Activiti engine's API](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#chapterApi) (preferably from a Grails service) to deploy your process model(s), start up individual instances of the process(es), and move through the various steps in the workflow.

   - You may need to pass information about your Grails domain objects as process variables, and then draw them back out again later. Teasing out where to let Grails persist the data in a domain object, and where to make Activiti keep it as a process variable is simply going to take some thought on the developer's part.

Generally, my rule of thumb is to let Activiti handle the *process*, and Grails handle everything else (UI, data persistence and manipulation, validation, etc.).

I recommend this approach so that you can still use Grails to manage all the user interface via Controllers and GSPs, and much of the object model via Domain objects and Services. There's nothing wrong with the UI the Activiti team is building, but it's based on [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home), which is its own Java/UI framework with its own character and philosophy. I'm sure a super-developer could combine them seamlessly, and probably already has, but unless s/he'll come down off the mountain and teach me, I'm going to have to limit the number of tools I'll try to master at once. :)

## How to Include Activiti as a Dependency

In your BuildConfig.groovy file, have the following in your dependencies and repositories closures:

```
repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    mavenRepo "https://maven.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public/"
    //any other repositories you need go here, including grailsCentral(), etc.
}
dependencies {
    compile("org.activiti:activiti-engine:5.13"){
        excludes "spring-beans"
    }
}
```

You don't have to exclude the spring-context dependencies, but Grails 2.3.1 does use a later version of Spring than Activiti 5.13. On 2/3 machines I've tried it on, that's fine, and Grails just uses the later version of Spring, ignoring the old one required by Activiti. However, [on one machine, the difference caused a persnickety exception that was difficult to track down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845734/grails-2-3-1-on-mac-classnotfound-nouniquebeandefinitionexception).